# перетаскивание ячеек html jquery

Tags: html, jquery, table

Есть ли в природе готовый плагин jquery для перетаскивания ячеек html ? чтоб в дальнейшем их можно было сохранить в базу новые значения позиций.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой плагин jQuery UI. В нем есть возможность делать сортирующиеся списки:

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Что остается сделать - ловить событие `update` ([ссылка на API](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update)), и написать обработчик события, который будет записывать изменения в базу данных:

```
$( ".selector tbody" ).sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {
     //здесь код отправки изменений в базу данных 
  }
});
```

NB. Для сортировки таблиц нужно [плагин вызывать из `tbody`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470775/using-jquery-ui-sortable-with-html-tables)